# HttpWebRequest returns empty text

Tags: c#, network-programming

When I try to fetch the content of this URL
http://www.yellowpages.com.au/qld/gatton/a-12000029-listing.html

```
using System.Net;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader objSR;
objSR = new StreamReader(resStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
string sResponse = objSR.ReadToEnd();
```

I don't get any response from the server. Please help me find out why this happens.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the `response.StatusCode` ?

Comment: This site seems like a bad mess to me. Doesn't even properly load in a browser and about 50% of the requests it returns 503 Service Unavailable (in the browser).

Answer (score 0):

It may well be looking at the user agent and refusing to serve content to a client that doesn't identify itself. Try setting the [UserAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent.aspx) property on your request object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like that site is checking the referrer url and may be serving up empty content if an invalid referrer is specified.

Try setting `request.Referer = "http://www.google.com";`. Experiment with the referrer to see if that changes the response. I'd also try the UserAgent property as Matthew suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the cause was that I previously had set the method to `HEAD` and in later revisions had the need to parse the body.